# Finding the set of analytic functions whose image is a subset of a given set

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Let $A=${$z\in\mathbb{C}||z|=1$} and $B=${$z\in\mathbb{C}||z|<2$}. I want to find the the set of analytic functions such that $f(B)\subset A$. Is there a way to solve this? Hope someone could help me out. Thanks

EDIT: I also would like to look at the case $f(A)\subset B$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You should be able to see which constant functions satisfy the requirement. As for non-constant holomorphic functions, consider what $f(B)$ is topologically and whether it can be contained in $A$.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any other way to prove that there are no non constant analytic functions without directly using the open mapping theorem?

Comment: Not that I know of. Why wouldn't you want to make use of that theorem?